# PHP: Variables sent via post are in the $_GET array and $_POST array is empty

Tags: php, post, http-post, postman

I am running a PHP server with the following code on it.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
            echo $_POST["username"];
            http_response_code(200);
        }
    }
?>
```

I **expected** the script **to return the username** if both username and password are set in the post request.
**However**, the **script returns nothing**. When debugging with Postman I found out that the first if statement passes - I am **sending a post request**, but the **$_POST array is empty**. I found out that **instead of the $_POST array**, the $_REQUEST array, specifically the **$_GET array contains** my **parameters**.

The server REQUEST_METHOD is set to POST, yet the $_GET array contains my parameters.

So this code is working:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
        if (isset($_GET["username"]) && isset($_GET["password"])) {
            echo $_GET["username"];
            http_response_code(200);
        }
    }
?>
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I have programmed with php some time ago, maybe I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Where is the code or HTML form that executes the `POST`? I'd guess if a form then the `method` is set to `GET`.

Comment: *"Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?"* - It seems reasonable to conclude that this is happening because your values are on the query string and not in the POST body.  Have you tried examining the request being sent to the code instead of only the code itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$_POST` and `$_GET` superglobals aren't named after the HTTP methods (at least not directly).

They are named after the HTML form `method` attribute values and care about where the data is in the request.

- `$_GET` is populated by data from the URL's query string
- `$_POST` is populated by application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data encoded data in the request body

You must be making a POST request but putting the data in the URL's query string. (Note that data in the query string is usually logged, in plain text, in standard web server logs, so it is a **really** bad place to put passwords)

Use the *Body* tab and not the *Params* tab to enter your data. Make sure you pick *form-data* or *x-www-form-urlencoded*.

[image: Sceenshot of Postman]